# Undefined Reference to Functions from .dll Library

Tags: c++, dll, codeblocks

Preface: I am using Code::Blocks software on a Windows 10 Machine and programming in C++. I am using libraries for the Princeton Instruments Scientific CCD camera.

I will try to be a specific as possible here. I am attempting to create a .dll file using multiple functions that control a Princeton Instruments Camera (PIcam). I am making this .dll because I want to embed this code (which is in C++) in a different Python program. Here is my current relevant main.cpp code:

```
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "picam.h"

// a sample exported function
void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

void DLL_EXPORT connectCamera()
{
    Picam_InitializeLibrary();
    PicamHandle camera;
    PicamCameraID id;
    //const pichar* string;
    //PicamAvailableData data;
    //PicamAcquisitionErrorsMask errors;
    //piint readoutstride = 0;

    if (Picam_OpenFirstCamera( &camera ) == PicamError_None )
        Picam_GetCameraID( camera, &id );
    else {
        Picam_ConnectDemoCamera(
            PicamModel_Pixis100F,
            "0008675309",
            &id );
            Picam_OpenCamera( &id, &camera );
        printf( "No Camera Detected, Creating Demo Camera\n" );
    }
}
```

But the compiler gives me [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtJAO.png) errors after I build my code. It claims that every single function I called is an undefined reference, even after I successfully linked the libraries in Code::Blocks.

I know that my libraries are linked correctly. All of these functions lie in the library Picam.lib, which I know is linked correctly. Here is the build-log code to show it:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -shared -Wl,--output-def=bin\Debug\libSampleDLL.def -Wl,--out-implib=bin\Debug\libSampleDLL.a -Wl,--dll -LC:\Users\Philip\Documents\CppProjects\SampleDLL obj\Debug\main.o  -o bin\Debug\SampleDLL.dll  -lPicam -luser32 -lPicam C:\Users\Philip\Documents\CppProjects\SampleDLL\Picam.lib
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z13connectCamerav':
C:/Users/Philip/Documents/CppProjects/SampleDLL/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `_imp__Picam_InitializeLibrary@0'
C:/Users/Philip/Documents/CppProjects/SampleDLL/main.cpp:21: undefined reference to `_imp__Picam_OpenFirstCamera@4'
C:/Users/Philip/Documents/CppProjects/SampleDLL/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `_imp__Picam_GetCameraID@8'
C:/Users/Philip/Documents/CppProjects/SampleDLL/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `_imp__Picam_ConnectDemoCamera@12'
C:/Users/Philip/Documents/CppProjects/SampleDLL/main.cpp:28: undefined reference to `_imp__Picam_OpenCamera@8'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Creating library file: bin\Debug\libSampleDLL.a
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
5 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I do not know what else to do to fix this. It seems like everything is right but the functions still cannot be identified in the library. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I know that my libraries are linked correctly.

Well then you're set, aren't you!

However if you're willing to keep an open mind and actually understand the linking process, you should probably know that gcc (which you're using) doesn't know what to do with `.lib` files, they're Microsoft library files. gcc's library files end with `.a` or `.so`.

Comment: Interesting that this doesn't generate a "can't read that library format" error message from the linker.

Comment: So, if g++ cannot handle .lib files, then why are they even available in the first place? Doesn't that make it impossible for any C++ compiler to even use library files if they are not available in the .so format? And by "I know they are linked correctly", I meant that I spent an hour troubleshooting the "library not connected" issue and then finally solved it.

Comment: I don't understand your question, I already said they work with `cl`.